# Reversing and complementing a dna sequence in python

Tags: python

I am having a certain problem when running my code, the console tells me that I have an AttributeError.

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

What could I do to fix my problem?

> 5. reverse_complement( )
>
> The next step is to write a function named reverse_complement that
> takes one argument seq. The argument seq is to be a string that
> contains information for the bases of a DNA sequence and return the
> reverse complement of that DNA sequence.
>
> To determine the reverse complement, the DNA sequence need be (1)
> reversed and (2) complemented.
>
> One way to reverse a string is to use the slicing value of [::-1]
>
> ```
> >>> reversed_seq = seq[::-1]
> ```
>
> To complement a DNA sequence is to replace all:
>
> all A's with T's
> all T's with A's
> all C's with G's
> all G's with C's
>
> One way to complement a DNA sequence is using the built-in Python
> function of replace( ). However, this approach requires you to be
> clever in order to get it to work correctly.
>
> Another way to complement a DNA sequence is to loop through all of the
> characters in the DNA sequence and use if statements to check for the
> different bases and then to use concatenation to build a new string
> using the complements of each each base.

```
def reverse_complement(seq):
    '''This function will reverse and then complement the given dna sequence.'''
    revSeq = seq[::-1]
    revSeq = revSeq.replace("A", "x")
    revSeq = revSeq.replace("T", "y")
    revSeq = revSeq.replace("G", "z")
    revSeq = revSeq.replace("C", "w")
    
    revSeq = revSeq.replace("x", "T")
    revSeq = revSeq.replace("y", "A")
    revSeq = revSeq.replace("z", "C")
    revSeq = revSeq.replace("w", "G")

    print(revSeq)
    return revSeq


# Tests for reverse_complement function. Should print True.
print ("\nreverse_complement")
print (reverse_complement('ATGCTTG') == 'CAAGCAT')
print (reverse_complement('AAAGGG') == 'CCCTTT')
print (reverse_complement('TTTCCC') == 'GGGAAA')
print (reverse_complement('ATCGATCAGTCCTAGCATCG') == 'CGATGCTAGGACTGATCGAT')
```

My test cases say they are true, but I am still getting the AttributeError.

Comment: @mkrieger1 no the order does not matter, the output just needs to be a reversely complemented string. I also tried doing an If Else statement but that also did not work out well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the (very handful) python sequence built-ins, like [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed). At the end, re-build the string with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
s = 'ATCGATCAGTCCTAGCATCG'

def complement(c):
  if c == 'A': return 'T'
  if c == 'T': return 'A'
  if c == 'C': return 'G'
  if c == 'G': return 'C'
  return c

''.join(map(complement, reversed(s)))            #'CGATGCTAGGACTGATCGAT'
```

---

Actually, python has an (almost forgotten) built-in [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) that does exactly that!

```
s = 'ATCGATCAGTCCTAGCATCG'
s[::-1].translate(str.maketrans('ATCG','TAGC'))  #'CGATGCTAGGACTGATCGAT'
```

You gotta love python.

Answer (score 0):

there is a built-in function in BioPython you can use

```
from Bio import Seq
seq = 'TTAACCGG'
print(Seq.reverse_complement(seq))
```

result:
CCGGTTAA